# webdriver_seleiunm 4.8.3: how to use driver from .cache file without searching for latest version

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver

while using Selenium 4.8.3, it is necessary to retrieve the driver version from a local .cache file rather than attempting to search and download the version each time.To overcome issues caused by VPN and proxy limitation and ensures that the test scenario does not fail due to connectivity issues preventing the driver from being instantiated.

Before migrating to Selenium 4, I relied on WebDriver Manager dependency  and this snippet code , which provided a convenient solution. I'm wondering if Selenium 4 offers a similar method or functionality that can achieve the same effect.

```
 public  WebDriver webDriver;
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().driverVersion("112.0.1722.34").setup();
            webDriver = new EdgeDriver() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use [WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) with Selenium 4, and the snippet of code you attached should be valid. If you have compatibility issues, be sure to update the [WebDriverManager dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to the latest version.

Instead, if you're searching for a Selenium-native solution, you should take a look at [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/). At the time of writing this, it's still in beta, though.